# How to Total per Month of Year as a Tablix Column in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a table with stats information per user, let's say

```
TABLE Stats
user varchar(50)
callsdate datetime
howmany INT
```

And I need to show a Tablix with the totals where the columns headings should be Jul-2012, Aug-2012, Sep-2012, etc., depending of what is there in the data.

Comment: Can you go into the properties of the field and then number and set it to date with the formatting you want? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately you need to set up a group at the report level that is a concatenation of the month and the year.

You could do this at the query level with something like:

```
select
  [user]
  , monthYear = left(datename(mm, callsdate), 3) + '-' + cast(datepart(yy, callsdate) as char(4))
  , howmany
from [Stats]
```

Or even do the aggregating at the query level if you can:

```
select
  [user]
  , monthYear = left(datename(mm, callsdate), 3) + '-' + cast(datepart(yy, callsdate) as char(4))
  , howmany = sum(howmany)
from [Stats]
group by [user]
  , monthYear = left(datename(mm, callsdate), 3) + '-' + cast(datepart(yy, callsdate) as char(4))
```

With this dataset at the report level you can easily group on the `monthYear` column as required for your Tablix.

You'll run into an issue with getting correct ordering; I would add another calculated column to the dataset:

```
select
  [user]
  , monthYear = left(datename(mm, callsdate), 3) + '-' + cast(datepart(yy, callsdate) as char(4))
  , monthYearOrder = cast(datepart(yy, callsdate) as char(4)) + right('0' + cast(datepart(mm, callsdate) as char(2)), 2)
  , howmany = sum(howmany)
from [Stats]
group by [user]
  , monthYear = left(datename(mm, callsdate), 3) + '-' + cast(datepart(yy, callsdate) as char(4))
  , monthYearOrder = cast(datepart(yy, callsdate) as char(4)) + right('0' + cast(datepart(mm, callsdate) as char(2)), 2)
```

This will allow you to group and order by `monthYearOrder` but still use the text from `monthYear`.

If you can't aggregate at the query level, you could do something similar with an expression in the report, e.g. as a calculated column in the dataset:

monthYear: `=CDate(Fields!callsdate.Value).ToString("MMM-yyyy")`

monthYearOrder: `=CDate(Fields!callsdate.Value).ToString("yyyyMM")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll need some time to test this! Most likely on Monday, as my boss wants me to do something else now. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Still didn't get a chance to get to this. I will.

Comment: Will not be able to work on this for another few days, but (a) I imagine your answer is right and (b) At least you put a lot of work into it. Thanks.